# prefetch or predownload some video data before play in videoview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I want to prefetch/predownload some data of video which is stored on my server.
Right now I streaming the video from the server, It requires some time to buffer then it will start playing video. So I want to prefetch some data of video so that when user clicks on it video get play without taking too much time.

How to achieve this can I store it in database some data or download file while set list of videos in listview.

Please help with this problem.I didn't understand what to do?

Comment: hey how did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer#) which as this feature and many more. [Demo](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo) repositorie also available.

Comment: can i attach exoplayer as the mediacontroller for videoview ?

Comment: @j2emanue no but Exoplayer 2 has a SimpleExoplayerView which is very convenient see here https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#getting-started